# Alternating math alphabets with unicode-math package in \(re)newcommand environment

Tags: unicode-math

I am trying to define some command to alternate between various alphabets in the unicode-math package. More specifically, my code is as follows

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\setmathfont[version=Pagella]{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}
\setmathfont[version=Termes]{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
\setmathfont[version=Default]{Latin Modern Math}

\renewcommand{\L}{$\mathversion{Termes}$\mathscr{L}}
\renewcommand{\H}{$\mathversion{Default}$\mathscr{H}}
\renewcommand{\l}{$\mathversion{Default}$\mathscr{L}}
\newcommand{\h}{$\mathversion{Pagella}$\mathscr{H}}
\newcommand{\q}{\vec{q}}
\newcommand{\dq}{\dot{\vec{q}}}

\begin{document}
This is a Lagrangian function $\L(\q,\dq,t)$, and this is the Hamiltonian $\H$.
This is a Lagrangian density $\l$, and this is a Hamiltonian density $\h$.
I want to take a derivative, so I'll go $\partial_t\L$, and this is still fine, but if I go to the double dollar enviroment, I get
$$
\partial_t\L
$$
and after it
\begin{equation}
\partial_t\L
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

and the output is this [which means I clearly do something wrong when using the double dollar sign](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27lpa.png)
I'd really like to know how to redefine the commands by keeping those specific four letters whithout having to copy and paste the entire sequence every time.
If anybody could help I'd gladly appreciate it, thanks a lot!

Comment: the intent of your commands is very hard to understand. you can not change math version inside math, and if you use `\L` outside of math mode then the `$` will make teh version switch in a math list on its own, and if you use `\L` in display math then you will have `$` which is ending textstyle math so naturally an error.

Comment: unrelated but never use `inputenc` with luatex `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` just warns that it should not be used, and does nothing)

Comment: And how could I get the same result? Also about the inputenc thanks! I always used it for the letters with accents, what alternative is best?

Comment: the encoding in luatex is fixed and always utf-8 (but by a completely different mechanism than inputenc uses)  to be honest I am struggling to guess what you want `\renewcommand{\L}{$\mathversion{Termes}$\mathscr{L}}` to do, do  do you want a script L from the termes font and not affect the rest of the expression (as written it generates errors and would make the entire math list use termes not just one L ?

Comment: My objective is to have that L written in that font as I do with all other maths characters such as "\partial", for example. I just want to be able to alternate between \L and \l with them keeping their particular font

Comment: For the rest of the expression I'd like to keep the default math mode, yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only change math version outside of math, it would be more efficient to use multiple math families in the same version but unicode-math not directly set up for that, so here I model a version switch like `\boldsymbol` which switches math version in a nested `\text`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
% never in luatex or xetex \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\setmathfont[version=Pagella]{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}
\setmathfont[version=Termes]{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
\setmathfont[version=Default]{Latin Modern Math}

\renewcommand{\L}{\text{\mathversion{Termes}$\mathscr{L}$}}
\renewcommand{\H}{\text{\mathversion{Default}$\mathscr{H}$}}
\renewcommand{\l}{\text{\mathversion{Default}$\mathscr{L}$}}
\newcommand{\h}{\text{\mathversion{Pagella}$\mathscr{H}$}}
\newcommand{\q}{\vec{q}}
\newcommand{\dq}{\dot{\vec{q}}}

\begin{document}
This is a Lagrangian function $\L(\q,\dq,t)$, and this is the Hamiltonian $\H$.
This is a Lagrangian density $\l$, and this is a Hamiltonian density $\h$.
I want to take a derivative, so I'll go $\partial_t\L$, and this is still fine, but if I go to the double dollar enviroment, I get
% never use $$ in latex$$
\[
\partial_t\L
\]%$$
and after it
\begin{equation}
\partial_t\L
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I tried the code and it won't display the \partial nor \q-\dq now, it's as if they aren't there
Edit: Not even the t, it shows the L with the right font and then only "(,,)"

Comment: It all worked by adding a \mathversion{Default} at the start of the document, now it's perfect! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Lost_in_the_Matrix oops yes or simply remove `version=Default` from the latin modern setting, so it goes to the default math version (which isn't called Default)